# Extract extensionAttribute from Computer properties in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Domain→OU=Client Computers→OU=Location

Each computers has an extensionAttribute1 value.

I need to get each computer's `extensionAttribute1` and export to a CSV file.

I ran below code, but was unable to get it right.  Tried few variation with no success.

I ran this first  (no error here):

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Location,OU=Client Computers,DC=ABC,DC=ABC1" -Properties *
```

Then I ran this:

```
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  Get-ADComputer $Computer -Filter * -Properties extensionAttribute5 |
    Export-Csv C:\computer_users.csv
}
```

and got the following error:

> Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
>   argument

I tried with parenthesis, commas, single quotes, double quotes, … just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ADComputer $Computer -Filter * ...
```

is the same as

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer -Filter * ...
```

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx) you'll see that the parameters `-Identity` and `-Filter` are mutually exclusive. Besides, you don't need the loop and the second `Get-ADComputer` call anyway. Simply select the properties you want from your first `Get-ADComputer` call and pipe the result to `Export-Csv`:

```
$ou = 'OU=Location,OU=Client Computers,DC=ABC,DC=ABC1'

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties extensionAttribute1 |
  Select-Object Name, extensionAttribute1, ... |
  Export-Csv 'C:\computer_users.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar.

I tried it this morning.  

I got the following message

Get-ADComputer : Missing an argument for parameter 'SearchBase'. Spec
ify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

Comment: My mistake. I made the OU a variable to shorten the statement a bit, but then forgot to actually add the variable to the command. Fixed.

Comment: It works perfect.  Thank you very much Ansgar.  Learning each day.